# Assemblies not found when running MVC5 project from external usb-drive

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, assemblies

When I open my solution and run my MVC 5.1 project from local c: drive it works. But when I copy and run the solution from an external usb drive (from the same computer) some assemblies can't be found.

For example:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0

What can be the cause for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. When copying the solution to the external usb drive I put the solution in a folder named with a "#" in the name, If so Microsoft Fusion will completely ignore the web.config for all assemblyBinding entries.